# jQuery autocomplete is slow in Firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery autocomplete component.

Problem :

1. Slow in moving to the next item when we press up or down arrow
2. In Chrome it is taking around 30 milliseconds to hover the next item. But in              Firefox and IE it is taking around 170 milliseconds.
3. Menu move function is slow. How can we overwrite this??

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that using the ajax aproach with autocomplete can be rather slow if your dataset is very large.

Your lack of detail in the question, regarding the size of your dataset and how you supply the data to the plugin, only gives us a chance to guess how you approach it.

I can only recommend you to output your dataset to the browser via JSON somehow and use it directly.